# Restore Last Directory for Open/Save Dialog Boxes separately

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio, WPF, C#, XAML.

My program has `Input` and `Output` buttons.

**Input** uses `OpenFileDialog`.
**Output** uses `SaveFileDialog`.

[image: Input Output]

I need each button to remember its last used directory, but `RestoreDirectory = true` causes both button's last directory to be the same. Each does not remember it's own directory separate.

---

```
// Input Button
//
private void btnInput_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Open 'Select File' Window
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog selectFile = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

    // Remember Last Dir
    selectFile.RestoreDirectory = true;

    // Show Window
    Nullable<bool> result = selectFile.ShowDialog();

    // Display Path
    if (result == true)
    {
        tbxInput.Text = selectFile.FileName;
    }
}   


// Output Button
//
private void btnOutput_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Open 'Save File' Window
    Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog saveFile = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();

    // Remember Last Dir
    saveFile.RestoreDirectory = true;

    // Show Window
    Nullable<bool> result = saveFile.ShowDialog();

    // Display Path
    if (result == true)
    {
        tbxOutput.Text = saveFile.FileName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an `InitialDirectory` property on the dialog controls? You could use that instead and store the values in your application state.

Comment: @DanWilson Save it to user config in AppData with `Settings.Default.Save();`?

Comment: You could. I think the key change is not relying on `RestoreDirectory`.